# Joomla - Como fazer o action de um formulário funcionar?

Tags: php, formulário, joomla

Estou aprendendo como fazer um próprio módulo em Joomla. 
Meu módulo **mod_planejamentomensal.php** está assim:

```
//No direct access 
defined('_JEXEC') or die;
require_once dirname(__FILE__) . '/helper.php';

Jhtml::_('jquery.framework');
Jhtml::_('jquery.ui');
JHtml::_('behavior.formvalidator');
JHtml::script(JURI::base() . '/modules/mod_planejamentomensal/js/jquery-3.3.1.js');
JHtml::script(JURI::base() . '/modules/mod_planejamentomensal/js/jquery.mask.js');
```

meu arquivo **default.php** tem meu formulário (que tem outros campos e algumas funções em jQuery mas não vou colocar tudo aqui para não ficar muito comprido:

```
 <div class="planj-mensal-form">
  <form method="post" name="frmCasdastra" class="form-validate" action="<?php JURI::base() . '/modules/mod_planejamentomensal/tmpl/adicionaForm.php' ?>">
    <div class="divTable">
        <div class="divTableRow">
            <div class="divTableColumn">
                <b>Solicitação nº:</b> <?php //echo $solicitacaoTemp; ?>
            </div>
        </div>


      <div class="divTableRow">
            <div class="divTableColumn divTableColumn1">
                <b>Agência:</b> <?php echo $grupo; ?>
            </div>
            <div class="divTableColumn divTableColumn2">
                <div class="divLabel"><label for="mes">Mês Referência:</label></div>
                <div class="divInput">
                <select name="mes">
                <?php 
                    $select = $planMensal->setSelect($mes, 'mes', date('m',strtotime('+1 month'))); 
                    echo $select;
                ?>
                </select>
                </div>
           </div>
        </div>
            <div class="divTableRow">
            <div class="divtableColumnBotao">
                <div class="divInput">
                    <input name="add" type="button" value="Adicionar mais um formulário" id="add">
              </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
  </form>  
</div>
```

Então, o action do meu formulário acima está apontando para o arquivo **adicionaForm.php**. 
Meu arquivo adicionaForm.php está assim:

```
 <?php

 defined('_JEXEC') or die;

$input = new JInput;
$teste = $input->get('mes',null);

echo "Show: ".$teste;
?>
```

Mas quando eu clico no botão de submit nada acontece... eu sei que deve ter alguma coisa aí em relação ao Joomla que eu estou fazendo errado.. tentei ler a documentação de formulários do Joomla mas não entendi muita coisa e também não achei maiores explicações ou exemplos na internet. Alguém poderia me dar alguma dica, por favor?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, primero eu pensei que o endereço do meu action estava errado de alguma forma mas consegui uma resposta de outro site. Meu código não estava funcionando por causa do tipo do input do botão.

Eu mudei de:

```
<input name="add" type="button" value="Adicionar mais um formulário" id="add">
```

Para:

```
 <input name="add" type="submit" value="Adicionar mais um formulário" id="add">
```

E funcionou normalmente!